# How to mute the iphone

Tags: objective-c

I want to know how can we adjust the volume of iPhone programmatically. I m working on an application, In that application i need to adjust the volume of iphone programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Without jailbreaking your device, you will not be able to adjust the system volume from your sandboxed application. The only volume you can control (from the systems volume bar) is if you are playing media inside your app.

### Jailbreak solution

```
// System Volume
AVSystemController *avsc = SharedAVSystemController;
[avsc setVolumeTo:sliderValue forCategory:@"UserInterfaceSoundEffects"];

// Ringtone Volume
AVSystemController *avsc = SharedAVSystemController;
[avsc setVolumeTo:sliderValue forCategory:@"Ringtone"];
```

### Usage

```
-(void)systemVolumeChange:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    float sliderValue = (float)slider.value;

    AVSystemController *avsc = SharedAVSystemController;
    [avsc setVolumeTo:sliderValue forCategory:@"UserInterfaceSoundEffects"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as of this moment there is no way to mute an iPhone programatically. An iPhone can only be muted using the volume control in the upper side.